# Jump in serial number based on MySQL database

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter

I am trying to generate registration number increase by one but some time it jump the serial number.
I am storing serial number in database and in next save based on last stored serial number increasing by one. but some time it jump by one or two, then continue rightly after some time it jumps again.

I tried simple plus one in stored data. expecting to increase by one in any case.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOHFE.png)

Comment: Why not just use the provided autoimcrement column? That said, I’d advise using something more robust and meaningful than just an incremental value for invoice numbers.

Comment: Leave creation of serial numbers to the database. And please don‘t post images of text data.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a function like this, and pass the registration number

```
public static function generateCustomID($id){
    if(strlen($id) == 1){
        $id_string = "NUR-000" . $id;
    }elseif(strlen($id) == 2){
        $id_string = "NUR-00" . $id;
    }elseif(strlen($id) == 3){
        $id_string = "NUR-0" . $id;
    }else{
        $id_string = "NUR-" . $id;
    }

    return $id_string;
}
```

You can also do something like thse

```
$reg= RegNumber::orderBy('id','desc')->first();
$reg_id="";
$rega="";
if($reg){
    $rega= new RegNumber;
    $rega->reg_no=($reg->reg_no+1);
    $rega->save();
    $reg_id=str_pad($rega->reg_no, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}else{

    $reg_id=str_pad(1, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $rega= new RegNumber;
    $rega->reg_no=1;
    $rega->save();
}
```

Comment: A better option would be to use the [str_pad](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) function.

Comment: yes, that could e good option

Comment: Actually based on online payment success form number will be increased. so there is a possibility of id against null registration number. so this solution will not solve my problem.